@salesforce directory missing in 'c:\\Users\\myUserName\\.vscode\\extensions\\salesforce.salesforcedx-vscode-core-62.9.1\\node_modules\\
PROBLEM:
A Salesforce project was created in VSCode using SFDX: Create Project with Standard project template (default).
The following is listed as a Problem in a VSCode Salesforce project.
[{
    "resource": "/c:/Users/myUserName/Desktop/salesforce_junk/debugger-project/sfdx-project.json",
    "owner": "_generated_diagnostic_collection_name_#0",
    "code": "768",
    "severity": 4,
    "message": "Unable to load schema from 'c:\\Users\\myUserName\\.vscode\\extensions\\salesforce.salesforcedx-vscode-core-62.9.1\\node_modules\\@salesforce\\schemas\\sfdx-project.schema.json': ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'c:\\Users\\myUserName\\.vscode\\extensions\\salesforce.salesforcedx-vscode-core-62.9.1\\node_modules\\@salesforce\\schemas\\sfdx-project.schema.json'.",
    "startLineNumber": 1,
    "startColumn": 1,
    "endLineNumber": 1,
     "endColumn": 2
}]

When I navigate to  c:\\Users\\myUserName\\.vscode\\extensions\\salesforce.salesforcedx-vscode-core-62.9.1\\node_modules\\ in Windows File Explorer, I am able to see that there is no @salesforce of salesforce subdirectory.  So the problem seems to be caused by the fact that there is no @salesforce or salesforce subdirectory.
SCOPE OF QUESTION:
What specific CLI commands or configurations do I need to change in order for a @salesforce or salesforce subdirectory to be created, containing a schemas\\sfdx-project.schema.json, so that the Problem notification in VSCode can be resolved?
DOWNSTREAM PROBLEMS:
Other downstream problems are emerging in the VSCode Salesforce project.  For example, SFDX: Authorize an Org hangs indefinitely without every returning any result.
But instead of being distracted by the downstream problems, let's limit the scope of this question to how to resolve the problem that there is no ``@salesforceorsalesforce subdirectory within c:\\Users\\myUserName\\.vscode\\extensions\\salesforce.salesforcedx-vscode-core-62.9.1\\node_modules\\, and that there is no schemas\\sfdx-project.schema.json within the missing @salesforce or salesforce subdirectory.
THINGS I HAVE TRIED:
I have researched this error message, and I have tried several things that have been suggested.  For example:

I confirmed that I am using JDK version 21.
I downgraded the Salesforce Extension Pack (Extended) to version 61.11.0.  I reinstalled extensions.  I also closed and then restarted VSCode.

But the problem persists.
